# How to change the order properties are serialized in C#

Tags: c#, linq, soapui

I have a list in C# with 4 items. This list is used to send a response in a web service and I need a specific order for the items, but I'm having a problem because, for some reason, the list changes the order when I fill it.

First, this is the class of the list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Mvm.SATWeb.Domain
{
    [Serializable, DataContract]
    public  class puntoDeAtencion
    {

        public puntoDeAtencion()
        {
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string codigoPuntoAtencion { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public decimal montoIngreso { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public decimal montoEgreso { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public decimal ingresoNeto { get; set; }         

   }
}
```

I use a SQL server query to fill the list with a dataset

```
        List<puntoDeAtencion> valores = new List<puntoDeAtencion>();
        DataSet ds;

        Database baseDatos = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        DbCommand comandoConsulta = baseDatos.GetStoredProcCommand("USP_RiesgoLiqui");
        comandoConsulta.CommandTimeout = 600000;
        baseDatos.AddInParameter(comandoConsulta, "@pvstrIdAgencia", DbType.String, "-1");
        baseDatos.AddInParameter(comandoConsulta, "@pvstrFechaInicial", DbType.String, FechaIni);
        baseDatos.AddInParameter(comandoConsulta, "@pvstrFechaFinal", DbType.String, FechaFin);

        comandoConsulta.CommandTimeout = 1000000;
        // baseDatos.ExecuteDataSet();

        ds = baseDatos.ExecuteDataSet(comandoConsulta);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count ; i++)
            {
            //  valores.Add(s)



                //valores.Add (new punptoDeAtencion(){}    
                valores.Add(new puntoDeAtencion() { codigoPuntoAtencion = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Agencia"]), montoIngreso = Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["INGRESONETO"]), montoEgreso = Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MONTOEGRESO"]), ingresoNeto = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00) });


               // var list1 = (from p in ds.Tables[0].Rows[i] select p).ToList();
        }
        }


        return valores.ToList<puntoDeAtencion>();
```

This is the response (Using SOAP UI, but when I debug show the same values in the response object)

```
<b:listaPuntosDeAtencion>
   <b:puntoDeAtencion>
      <b:codigoPuntoAtencion>001</b:codigoPuntoAtencion>
      <b:ingresoNeto>0</b:ingresoNeto>
      <b:montoEgreso>53266155.0000</b:montoEgreso>
      <b:montoIngreso>138285187.0000</b:montoIngreso>
   </b:puntoDeAtencion>
```

and this is how it should be

```
<listaPuntosDeAtencion> 
    <puntoDeAtencion> 
        <codigoPuntoAtencion>00654</codigoPuntoAtencion> 
        <montoIngreso>79000.0</montoIngreso> 
        <montoEgreso>30000.0</montoEgreso> 
        <ingresoNeto>0.0</ingresoNeto> 
    </puntoDeAtencion>
```

I want to order the list or the response, I don't know if LINQ works in this case.

Comment: This is not about a list order -- you always show only one object. You seem to prefer a specified order of properties in the serialized object. If so, why is that important?

Comment: Because the response will be used for other service an need this specific order.

Comment: Well, use the `Order` property of `[DataMember]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order them by using Order on DataMember like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Mvm.SATWeb.Domain
{
    [Serializable, DataContract]
    public  class puntoDeAtencion
    {

        public puntoDeAtencion()
        {
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public string codigoPuntoAtencion { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public decimal montoIngreso { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public decimal montoEgreso { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public decimal ingresoNeto { get; set; }         

   }
}
```

Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx